# $\liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_{n+1}-a_n > 0 \Longrightarrow \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n/n > 0$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm currently studying real analysis and I have a problem I haven't been able to solve yet.

The problem goes as follows: Let $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^+$ be a nondecreasing sequence of real numbers such that $\liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} (a_{n+1} - a_n) >0$. Show that $\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_n}{n} >0$.

My attempt:

If $\liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} (a_{n+1} - a_n) >0$ then $a_{n+1} - a_n = 0$ con only be true for finitely many $n \in \mathbb{N}$ by definition of $\liminf$. Also $a_{n+1} - a_n < 0$ can not be possible for any $n$ since the sequence is nondecreasing.

Then, there is a $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for every $n>N$, $a_{n+1} - a_n >0$, or $a_{n+1}>a_n$. I got here and got stuck. I'm trying using the definition of $\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_n}{n} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (\sup_{m >n} (\frac{a_m}{m}))$. Any tips on how to proceed? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define
$$
L := \liminf_{n\to\infty}\,(a_{n+1}-a_n).
$$
By assumption, $L>0$. This means that for $N$ sufficiently large, we must have $\inf_{n\geq N}(a_{n+1}-a_n)\geq\frac{L}{2}>0$.

This implies that in particular, $a_{N+1}\geq a_N+\frac{L}{2}$. But also
$$
a_{N+2}\geq a_{N+1}+\frac{L}{2}\geq a_N+2\cdot\frac{L}{2}.
$$
Continuing in this way, you have that
$$
a_{N+k}\geq a_N+k\cdot\frac{L}{2}.
$$
But this implies that for $n\geq N$ written as $n=N+k$, we have
$$
\frac{a_n}{n}=\frac{a_{N+k}}{N+k}\geq\frac{a_N+k\cdot\frac{L}{2}}{N+k}.
$$

Can you see from here that as $k\to\infty$, these terms get closer and closer to $\frac{L}{2}>0$? Thus the $\limsup$ must be at least that large.

Comment: Thanks, pretty clear and was easy to follow

Answer (score 0):

If $\liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} (a_{n+1} - a_n) =d>0$ then $a_{n+1} - a_n>d/2$ for $n\ge N$. Therefore,for $n>N$,
$$
a_n=a_N+\sum_{k=N+1}^n (a_{k}-a_{k-1})\ge a_N+(n-N-1)d/2=C+dn/2
$$
and,consequently,
$$
\frac{a_n}{n}\ge \frac{C}{n}+\frac{d}{2}
$$
and
$$
\limsup \frac{a_n}{n}\ge \frac d{2}.
$$